# Alert Dialog con RecyclerView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

Genero un AlertDialog personalizado, el layout que cargo tiene un título, un recyclerview y un textview, cuando genero el AlertDialog relleno el recyclerview desde la Base de Datos de la misma forma en la que lo hago en una actividad normal, pero en este caso no me muestra nada de lo que deberia de mostrar en el recyclerview, el problema no está en el arreglo ya que al depurar me muestra que tiene un tamaño de dos, la cantidad que debería de mostrar, pero al abrir el AlertDialog no me muestra nada, aquí el código:
**MI ADAPTER**

```
public class AdapterDialogListadoArticulos  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDialogListadoArticulos.ViewHolderDialogListadoArticulos>  {
    ArrayList<ConstructorListadoArticulos> listArticulos;

    public AdapterDialogListadoArticulos(ArrayList<ConstructorListadoArticulos> listArticulos) {
        this.listArticulos = listArticulos;
    }


    static class ViewHolderDialogListadoArticulos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView descripcion, cantidadUnitario, total, id;
        ImageView imageView;
        Context context;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public ViewHolderDialogListadoArticulos(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            descripcion = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_articuloPedido);
            imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_InfoAdicionalArticuloPedido);
            cantidadUnitario = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_unitarioArticuloPedido);
            total = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_totalArticuloPedido);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutArticulo);
            id = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.idOculto);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderDialogListadoArticulos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemlist_pedido_articulo, null, false);
        return new ViewHolderDialogListadoArticulos(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDialogListadoArticulos holder, int position) {
        holder.descripcion.setText(listArticulos.get(position).getDescripcion());
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(listArticulos.get(position).getNotas());
        holder.cantidadUnitario.setText(listArticulos.get(position).getCantidadUnitario());
        holder.total.setText(listArticulos.get(position).getTotal());
        holder.id.setText(listArticulos.get(position).getID());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listArticulos.size();
    }
}
```

**XML DEL LAYOUT DEL DIALOG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bordeabajoazul"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/detalles"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegro"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView123">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerDialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/subtotal_pedido"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView46"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/total_dos_puntos"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_total"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EL CODIGO DONDE GENERO EL ALERTDIALOG Y TRAIGO LOS DATOS**

```
DatosBasicos datosBasicos = new DatosBasicos();
AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "admin", null, datosBasicos.versionSQL);
 Float importe_compra;
 public void info(View view){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_info_pago_articulos, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        TextView view_total = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.view_total);
        view_total.setText(nf.format(importe_compra));

        listArticulosDialog = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerView recyclerDialog = (RecyclerView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerDialog);
        recyclerDialog.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        articulosCompra();

        adapterDialogListadoArticulos = new AdapterDialogListadoArticulos(listArticulosDialog);
        recyclerDialog.setAdapter(adapterDialogListadoArticulos);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    private void articulosCompra(){
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        ConstructorListadoArticulos constructorListadoArticulos = null;
        Cursor cursor = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("Select descripcion, cantidad, costo, importe, notas, id from comprasDetalle where no_compra = 1, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            constructorListadoArticulos = new ConstructorListadoArticulos();
            constructorListadoArticulos.setDescripcion(cursor.getString(0));
            String cantidad = cursor.getString(1);
            Float costo = cursor.getFloat(2);
            constructorListadoArticulos.setCantidadUnitario(cantidad + " x " + nf.format(costo));
            Float total = cursor.getFloat(3);
            constructorListadoArticulos.setTotal(nf.format(total));
            String notasIf = cursor.getString(4);
            if (!notasIf.isEmpty()){
                constructorListadoArticulos.setNotas(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                constructorListadoArticulos.setNotas(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            constructorListadoArticulos.setID(cursor.getString(5));

            listArticulosDialog.add(constructorListadoArticulos);
        }
        cursor.close();
        BaseDeDatos.close();
    }
```